# When migrating old to new Google Spreadsheets, is it possible to retain the same URL?

Tags: redirect, google-sheets

I am trying to determine if, when I migrate a Google Spreadsheet from the old to new version, it is possible to keep the same URL.

If possible, how do I do this - through using redirects, or some other way?

If through redirects, how so?

Answer (score 0):

I think not because it is the URL that effectively determines whether `new` or `old`, not `new` or `old` working on one or other URL.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but "whether new or old, not new or old" is somewhat vague. Can you clarify? If I know what you mean, you cannot use the same URL for both, and you cannot redirect either. This is what I am thinking, but am trying to verify. The URL I am using is very important, and don't want to migrate my spreadsheet from old to new google spreadsheet before confiming if I have to create a new URL althogether. Thanks!